# Postman Express.js Response Body is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I have been stuck on this problem for a day. I cannot solve.

I have a VERY simple node app.

```js
const express = require("express");
const port = 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Body: ", req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
})

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

If I run this in a browser using any code extracted from Postman - it returns the expected result:

```js
Body:  { test: 'defrejbar',
  email: 'jsette@email.com',
  password: '43747638bar' }
```

However, if I run the EXACT same function directly from Postman, I receive an empty response.

[image: Screenshot of postman request]

I have tried adding body-parser, however that did not work. The only solution I have, would be to resort to Param Queries (which work), however I would prefer to be running with Response Body.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you screenshot your postman request?

Comment: Gotta use a res.send or res.json . It seems you are only seeing it in the browser's console but postman need a response

Comment: Exactly: your node server isn't sending anything back. Add `res.json(req.body);`

Comment: @HenryLy *server console

Comment: Even when I add `res.json(req.body);`  it still returns a blank result. The console returns Body:  {} and Postman response is blank

Comment: i had once a problem with the port, try a another port like 8080

Comment: tried 3 other ports, all responded the same. i.e. Blank req.body

Comment: Your code is fine, I just copied it to my own project and everything works. Postman response body is correct as well. Something else should be the issue, my quess is that something in your postman configuration is wrong.

Comment: Hmmm thanks @Reyno - this is what I suspected. I may need to reinstall Postman or revert back to original settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Reyno Pointed me in the right direction.

There was no issue with the code - it was a Postman issue. I'm not sure of the exact setting, but all I did was create a new Collection and added a new Request. The only difference between the 2 collections, is the old one has a heap of existing Requests - each with different endpoint.

Weird... but it worked. Hope it helps someone else out there with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but when I select `x-www-form-urlencoded` of postman it displays my response body.